# Is there 'Not' operator in Burningwave Classhunter criteria API?

Tags: java

Is it possible with burningwave classhunter to find classes WITHOUT a no-params constructor?
It's easy to get classes WITH no-op constructor, e.g.:

```
SearchConfig.forPaths(classPath)
        .by(ClassCriteria.create().allThoseThatMatch((cls) -> {
                return cls.isAnnotationPresent(ManagedBean.class);
            }).and().byMembers(
                ConstructorCriteria.withoutConsideringParentClasses().allThoseThatMatch((constructor) -> {
                    return constructor.getParameterCount() == 0;
                })
            )
        );
```

Of course, negating constructor predicate results in classes WITH 1-or-more-params constructor INDEPENDENTLY OF there is no-params constructor or not. Seems, there is no 'Not' operator(or any other obvious negate) which can be applied at .byMembers() or .allThoseThatMatch() level.

Answer (score 4):

Which version are you using? In the latest version you can find the method `negate` that solves the problem:

```java
SearchConfig.forPaths(classPath)
.by(ClassCriteria.create().allThoseThatMatch((cls) ->
        cls.isAnnotationPresent(ManagedBean.class)
    ).and(
        ClassCriteria.create().byMembers(
            ConstructorCriteria.withoutConsideringParentClasses().allThoseThatMatch((constructor) ->
                constructor.getParameterCount() == 0
            )
        ).negate()
    ).and().byMembers(
        ConstructorCriteria.withoutConsideringParentClasses().allThoseThatMatch((constructor) ->
            constructor.getParameterCount() > 0
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```java
SearchConfig.forPaths(classPath)
.by(ClassCriteria.create().allThoseThatMatch((cls) -> 
        cls.isAnnotationPresent(ManagedBean.class) && StaticComponentContainer.Constructors.findFirst(
                ConstructorCriteria.withoutConsideringParentClasses().allThoseThatMatch(constructor -> constructor.getParameterCount() == 0), cls) == null
    ).and().byMembers(
        ConstructorCriteria.withoutConsideringParentClasses().allThoseThatMatch((constructor) -> 
            constructor.getParameterCount() > 0
        )
    )
);
```